# Using Arrays in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

So i'm trying to make a page that will pull out a fact from an array and print it out.

```
var fact = [
        {
        id: 1,
        fact: "Cutis Anserina is the medical term for goosebumps.",
        question: "What common occurence is Cutis Anserina the medical term for?"
        option1: "Goosebumps",
        option2: "Hiccups",
        option3: "Laughter",
        option4: "Sneezing",
        correct: option1
        },
          {
        id: 2,
        fact: "The famous nursery rhyme,“Ringa Ringa Roses”, was actually based on the Black Death.",
        question: "What historical event is “Ringa Ringa Roses” based on?",
        option1: "The Great Depression",
        option2: "American Civil War",
        option3: "The Black Death",
        option4: "Indian Independence Struggle",
        correct: option3
        },
          {
        id: 3,
        fact: "Gobind Behari Lal is the first Indian to have won the famed Pulitzer Prize for Literature",
        question: "Who is the first Indian to win the Pulitzer Price?",
        option1: "Vijay Seshadri",
        option2: "Gobind Behari Lal",
        option3: "Jhumpa Lahiri",
        option4: "Dr. Siddhartha Mukherjee",
        correct: option2
        },
          {
        id: 4,
        fact: "OVI Intaglio is an ink from Swiss firm SLCPA and is used in the printing of watermark on Indian currency notes",
        question: "What ink is used to print the watermark on Indian currency notes?",
        option1: "OVI Intaglio",
        option2: "Parker Supreme",
        option3: "Bril Blue",
        option4: "L'ink special",
        correct: option1
        },
          {
        id: 5,
        fact: "The inhabitants of the planet Earth are called Tellurians",
        question: "The inhabitants of which planet are known as Tellurians?",
        option1: "Saturn",
        option2: "Jupiter",
        option3: "Mars",
        option4: "Earth",
        correct: option4
        },
        ];
```

i need the program to take out only the fact when id="1", "2" etc. This page is supposed to pull out only the data marked as "fact" from array for the respective ids. Please tell me what i can add or remove
Please help :(

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code. What did you try that failed?

Comment: `var itemWithId2 = fact.find(function(f) { return f.id === 2 });`

Comment: @user3297291 thanks that worked :)

Comment: Make sure you understand what's happening as well. Only copying the solution might not help you out on the long term ;)